# Stopwords can't delete words in R

Tags: r, tm

I tried to delete words using text containing stopwords. But this is happening.

```
library(corpus)
library(tm)
tokpedClean <- read.csv("D:/AS/tokpedClean5.csv")
head(tokpedClean)
tokpedCleanCor = Corpus(VectorSource(tokpedClean$text))

removeURL <- function(x) gsub("http[^[:space:]]*", "", x)
docsClean <- tm_map(docs, removeURL)
inspect(docsClean[1:5])
```

And other preprocessing, and also tokenizing.

```
tokenizer=function(x) strsplit(x, split = ' ')
docsClean=tm_map(docsClean, tokenizer)
inspect(docsClean[1:5])
```

Next step is stopwords

```
cStopwordID <- readLines("D:/AS/swID.csv")
stop <- tm_map(docsClean, removeWords, cStopwordID)
```

But the console show this

> Error in UseMethod("removeWords", x) :
>
> > no applicable method for 'removeWords' applied to an object of class "list"

I tried to convert to data frame, but still erro

> Error in UseMethod("removeWords", x) :
>
> > no applicable method for 'removeWords' applied to an object of class "data frame"

**What should I do?**

Comment: I think you should convert to `DocumentTermMatrix()` first

Comment: Your stopwords need to be a vector, not a data.frame or a list.